# How to refetch data with apollo refetchQueries and update loading status?

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo

I have two Queries

```
const LIST_CARD_SETS_QUERY = gql`
  {
    cardSets {
      id
      name
    }
  }
`;

const ADD_NEW_CARD_SET = gql`
  mutation($name: String!) {
  createCardSet(name: $name) {
    id
    name
  }
}`
```

And i try to refetch query LIST_CARD_SETS_QUERY after mutatuion like this

```
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(LIST_CARD_SETS_QUERY, { notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true });
  const [onCreateCardSet] = useMutation(ADD_NEW_CARD_SET, { refetchQueries: [{ query: LIST_CARD_SETS_QUERY}]});
```

But loading status after mutation doesn't update.

Comment: you're not using loading from mutation - see docs

Comment: I thought that loading status should be updated where I use LIST_CARD_SETS_QUERY like refetchQueries in  const { data, loading, error }

Comment: mutation has own loading, you can invoke query's `refetch` from mutation onComplete